# SQL Unique results

Tags: sql

My query is:

Table name: `employee`

```
id(pk) name    salary
1      prasad  1000
2      prasad  2000
3      gopi    3000
4      gopi    3500
5      seenu   2500
6      nag     1000
```

I want get only seenu and nag records. Above table column name is not unique.

Comment: format the view of your table so we can see it clearly, http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You need to specify the conditions better. Do you want the _specific_ names, do you want IDs greater than 4, do you want names that aren't duplicated?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds to me like you want to find **only** the records that don't have a duplicate (i.e. names which occur only once):

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee e
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT e2.ID
       FROM Employee e2 
       WHERE e2.name = e.name AND e2.ID <> e.ID)
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends entirely on the conditions you're trying to match against. If you want those specific names, use:

```
select * from employee where name in ('seenu','nag');
```

If you want IDs above 4:

```
select * from employee where id > 4;
```

If you want non-duplicate names:

```
select * from employee group by name having count(*) = 1;
```

As you can see, there are numerous possibilities, depending on your actual needs (which should be fleshed out a little more).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name 
FROM employee 
GROUP by name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`WHERE`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) and [`IN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) clause here:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE name IN ('seenu', 'nag')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the limitted detail you provided, I can only quess, but lets say

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE name IN ('seenu','nag')
```